Prove $\left(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2\right)^3\ge8\left(x_1^3x_2^3+\cdots+x_{n-1}^3x_n^3\right)$

Let $x_1$, $x_2\dots$, $x_n$ be non-negative real numbers, prove that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^3\ge8\sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{n-1}}x_i^3x_{i+1}^3.$$

I have a brutal proof by induction. Assume the inequality is true for $n$, then for $n+1$, pick the smallest variable $x_t$.
I will only demonstrate the most difficult case, that is when $x_t$ is in the middle. Let $m^2=x_t^2+x_{t+1}^2$, after applying the $n$-case to variables $(x_1,\dots,x_{t-1},m,x_{t+2},\dots,x_{n+1})$, we are left to prove that
$$m^3x_{t-1}^3+m^3x_{t+2}^3\ge x_{t-1}^3x_t^3+x_t^3x_{t+1}^3+x_{t+1}^3x_{t+2}^3.\\\\\iff\left(x_t^2+x_{t+1}^2\right)^3\left(x_{t-1}^3+x_{t+2}^3\right)^2\ge\left(x_{t-1}^3x_t^3+x_t^3x_{t+1}^3+ x_{t+1}^3 x_{t+2}^3\right)^2.$$
Let $x_{t-1}=b+x$, $x_t=b$, $x_{t+1}=b+y$, $x_{t+2}=b+z$, then the inequality above becomes
$$23 b^{12}+(78 x+60 y+78 z) b^{11}+\left(141 x^2+252 y x+126 z x+72 y^2+141 z^2+198 y z\right) b^{10}+\left(152 x^3+468 y x^2+126 z x^2+396 y^2 x+126 z^2 x+378 y z x+44 y^3+152 z^3+360 y z^2+234 y^2 z\right) b^9+\left(105 x^4+516 y x^3+42 z x^3+720 y^2 x^2+126 z^2 x^2+378 y z x^2+372 y^3 x+42 z^3 x+378 y z^2 x+594 y^2 z x+12 y^4+105 z^4+390 y z^3+423 y^2 z^2+138 y^3 z\right) b^8+\left(42 x^5+360 y x^4+780 y^2 x^3+42 z^2 x^3+126 y z x^3+660 y^3 x^2+42 z^3 x^2+378 y z^2 x^2+594 y^2 z x^2+216 y^4 x+126 y z^3 x+594 y^2 z^2 x+558 y^3 z x+42 z^5+270 y z^4+456 y^2 z^3+246 y^3 z^2+36 y^4 z\right) b^7+\left(7 x^6+144 y x^5+540 y^2 x^4+700 y^3 x^3+14 z^3 x^3+126 y z^2 x^3+198 y^2 z x^3+378 y^4 x^2+126 y z^3 x^2+594 y^2 z^2 x^2+558 y^3 z x^2+72 y^5 x+198 y^2 z^3 x+558 y^3 z^2 x+324 y^4 z x+7 z^6+108 y z^5+315 y^2 z^4+262 y^3 z^3+63 y^4 z^2\right) b^6+\left(24 y x^6+216 y^2 x^5+480 y^3 x^4+396 y^4 x^3+42 y z^3 x^3+198 y^2 z^2 x^3+186 y^3 z x^3+126 y^5 x^2+198 y^2 z^3 x^2+558 y^3 z^2 x^2+324 y^4 z x^2+12 y^6 x+186 y^3 z^3 x+324 y^4 z^2 x+108 y^5 z x+18 y z^6+126 y^2 z^5+180 y^3 z^4+66 y^4 z^3\right) b^5+\left(36 y^2 x^6+192 y^3 x^5+270 y^4 x^4+132 y^5 x^3+66 y^2 z^3 x^3+186 y^3 z^2 x^3+108 y^4 z x^3+21 y^6 x^2+186 y^3 z^3 x^2+324 y^4 z^2 x^2+108 y^5 z x^2+108 y^4 z^3 x+108 y^5 z^2 x+18 y^6 z x+21 y^2 z^6+72 y^3 z^5+45 y^4 z^4\right) b^4+\left(32 y^3 x^6+108 y^4 x^5+90 y^5 x^4+22 y^6 x^3+62 y^3 z^3 x^3+108 y^4 z^2 x^3+36 y^5 z x^3+108 y^4 z^3 x^2+108 y^5 z^2 x^2+18 y^6 z x^2+36 y^5 z^3 x+18 y^6 z^2 x+12 y^3 z^6+18 y^4 z^5\right) b^3+\left(18 y^4 x^6+36 y^5 x^5+15 y^6 x^4+36 y^4 z^3 x^3+36 y^5 z^2 x^3+6 y^6 z x^3+36 y^5 z^3 x^2+18 y^6 z^2 x^2+6 y^6 z^3 x+3 y^4 z^6\right) b^2+\left(6 y^5 x^6+6 y^6 x^5+12 y^5 z^3 x^3+6 y^6 z^2 x^3+6 y^6 z^3 x^2\right) b+x^6 y^6+2 x^3 y^6 z^3\ge0,$$
which is true.
Are there any nice proofs?

If $x_{t-1} = x_{t+2} = 1$ and $x_{t} = x_{t+1} = k$, then your inequality reduces to $(2k^2)^3 \cdot 2^2 \geq (k^3 + k^6 + k^3)^2 \Leftrightarrow 32 k^6 \geq k^{12} + 4k^9 + 4k^6$, which is false for large $k$. Did you assume any ordering on $x_{t-1},x_{t},x_{t+1},x_{t+2}$?

@SeewooLee: But the index $t$ is chosen such that $x_t$ is the smallest of all $x_i$.

@MartinR Oh I missed that, thanks.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &m^3x_{t-1}^3+m^3x_{t+2}^3 -  (x_{t-1}^3x_t^3+x_t^3x_{t+1}^3+x_{t+1}^3x_{t+2}^3)\\
 ={}& (m^3 - x_t^3)x_{t-1}^3 + (m^3 - x_{t+1}^3)x_{t+2}^3 - x_t^3 x_{t+1}^3\\
 \ge{}& (m^3 - x_t^3)x_t^3 + (m^3 - x_{t+1}^3)x_t^3 - x_t^3 x_{t+1}^3\\
 ={}& x_t^3(2m^3 - x_t^3 - 2x_{t+1}^3)\\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use $m^3 = (x_t^2 + x_{t+1}^2)^{3/2} \ge x_t^3$ and $m^3 = (x_t^2 + x_{t+1}^2)^{3/2} \ge x_{t+1}^3$ and $2m^3 - x_t^3 - 2x_{t+1}^3 \ge 0
\iff 4(x_t^2 + x_{t+1}^2)^3 \ge (x_t^3 + 2x_{t+1}^3)^2$.

Can you explain the last step?

@youthdoo Do you mean $4(x_t^2 + x_{t+1}^2)^3 \ge (x_t^3 + 2x_{t+1}^3)^2$? It suffices to prove that $4(x_t^2 + x_{t+1}^2)^3 \ge (2x_t^3 + 2x_{t+1}^3)^2$ or $4x_t^2x_{t+1}^2(3x_t^2 - 2x_t x_{t+1} + 3x_{t+1}^2) \ge 0$.

Thanks. I can  understand it now.

$$8\sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{n-1}}x_i^3x_{i+1}^3\leq 8\sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{n-1}}x_i^2x_{i+1}^2\sqrt{\sum_{i=1,\text{odd}}^n x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=2,\text{even}}^n x_i^2}\leq 8 (\sum_{i=1,\text{odd}}^n x_i^2)(\sum_{i=2,\text{even}}^n x_i^2)\sqrt{\sum_{i=1,\text{odd}}^n x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=2,\text{even}}^n x_i^2}=8(\sum_{i=1,\text{odd}}^n x_i^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}(\sum_{i=2,\text{even}}^n x_i^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\leq  \left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^3.$$ where the last step is AM-GM.
2nd way
WLOG $x_1\geq x_n$. The derivative with respect to $x_n$ is
$$6x_n\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^2-24x_n^2x_{n-1}^3\geq6x_n(2x_n^2+x_{n-1}^2)^2-24x_n^2x_{n-1}^3\geq96x_n\left(2x_n^2\frac1{27}x_{n-1}^6\right)^{\frac24}-24x_n^2x_{n-1}^3=24x_n^2x_{n-1}^3\left(\sqrt{\frac{32}{27}}-1\right)\geq0.$$
Thus, it suffices to prove the problem for $x_n=0$, so we can induct. $n=1,2$ is easy.
